# Checking if a field exists in Firebase real time database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a Firebase database in my Android app. This is the structure of the child `Users`:

[image]

As you may see in the picture, there are items that have a field called `imageURL` and other items that don´t have the field called `imageURL`.

This is the piece of code from my app where I get the value from the field `imageURL`:

```
fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid());

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                com.mpidesarrollo.buju.Model.User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                username.setText(user.getUsername());


                if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                    image_profile.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(image_profile);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

If the field imageURL doesn´t exist in the database I get an exception at line:

```
if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
```

Caused because the field `imageURL` doesn´t exist.

How can I check if the field exists to avoid the exception?

Comment: .getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid()).orderbyChild("imageURL ").equal("default")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check if the field exists to avoid the exception?

There are two ways in which you can solve this. The first one would be to check that `imageURL` property for existence:

```
if(dataSnapshot.child("imageURL").exists()) {
    //Do your logic
}
```

Or you can check the `imageURL` field for nullity:

```
if(user.getImageURL() != null) {
    //Do your logic
}
```

Comment: How would you decide between using one way or the other?

Comment: @auspicious99 The first one check if a value of a single property exists, while the second one checks if the value of a field that exists in an entire object is not null.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I was thinking in terms of performance, etc.; posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258532/checking-for-existence-of-a-field-in-firebase-real-time-database and got an answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You get exception  because of variable is null and you are try to check the value on this line.

```
if (user.getImageURL().equals("default"))
```

If you had field in your Model and that field it not available in firebase then this will return null.

```
if(user.getImageURL()!=null) //checking field is available or not
{ 
    // imageURL exist in the database
    if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                image_profile.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            } else {
                Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(image_profile);
            }
}
else{
    // imageURL doesn´t exist in the database
}
```