# Checking for existence of a field in firebase real-time database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

For firebase functions, we may sometimes need to check if a field in the real-time database exists, e.g., we may be looping through all the user records in the real-time database, and only some of the users may have a field, say, "car". As I understand it from [the selected answer in the SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58745324/checking-if-a-field-exists-in-firebase-real-time-database), we can either call `exists()` or check for null.

The first one would be to check `car` for existence:

```
if(dataSnapshot.child("car").exists()) {
    //Do something
}
```

The second one would be to check the `car` field for nullness:

```
if(dataSnapshot.child("car").val() != null) {
    //Do the other thing
}
```

The question is, how do these two ways compare, firstly, in terms of results? `exists() === false` is the same as `null` and `exists() === true` is the same as `!null`, or are there any special cases to consider? Secondly, how about performance? Is a null check faster, does it use fewer resources (memory, etc.), compared to the function call that is `exists()`? Or is it purely a matter of preference/taste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be given by taking a look at the API source code.

Let's start with the .exists() method. At [this link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/a5d87bc5c5d6360d5fa2386fe351937463bc45b8/packages/database/src/api/Reference_impl.ts) (row 361), you can see that the exists method perform a call to the underlying isEmpty() method.

In the same file, at row 462, we can see the implementation of the val() method: it call the val() method of the inner node. Well, let's then get a look at it: at [this link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/a5d87bc5c5d6360d5fa2386fe351937463bc45b8/packages/database/src/core/snap/ChildrenNode.ts#L197), at row 197, you can see that the very first thing that the val() method will do is calling the isEmpty() method and, if it is true, it will return a null value.

This tells us that the two methods (using exists() or evaluating the return value of val() and checking if it is null or not) gives the same result.

Let's get to the performance side: both ways performs the same. If you're going to call these methods intensively, exists() will perform less inner calls, so it should be the preferred one.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the availability of these source code files. Thanks for checking.